# How to configure telnet in Windows 8?

Tags: networking, windows-8, proxy, http, telnet

I want to use telnet to understand the working of web and networks.
However, whenever I type `telnet "URL" 8080`, it shows
`Could not open connection to the host, on port 8080: Connect Failed`.

I work in a proxy network with a different port.
Since I don't know much about networks so I dont know what the problem is.

Any advice is invited.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using port 80? The error means the machine you are attempting to connect to is not listening on port 80. You will never connect if it isn't listening.

Have you tried something simple like telnet URL or telnet DestinationIPAddress without specifying a port?

If the destination machine is on the local network scan it with a port scanner like NMAP and see what ports it is listening on. Once you know the ports that it is listening on, use those.

Comment: Sorry, Its a typo. I tried port 8080